# How to create a private message system with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am implementing simple private messaging application without any package.

Message table have following columns
id, from_id, to_id, message, created_at

I want user to show messages like below example-

User1: Hi
User2: Hello

User1: How are you?
User1: Whats going on?
User2: Fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. You should create pivot table with two keys pointed to `id` in `users` table:

```
Schema::create('messages_pivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('from_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('to_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('message');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('messages_pivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('from_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('to_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

You can use [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to work with this pivot table or you could create a model for it.

Comment: Not really useful also private messaging with only 2 users don't necessarily need to be many to many relationship.

Comment: I never downvote anyone but it sounds like it didn't work for someone else either.

Answer (score 1):

Create Both tables **Conversations** and **Messages** use conversation_id between users if exists then add message and store who sent the message using user_id in messages table.

```
class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->boolean('is_seen')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('deleted_from_sender')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('deleted_from_receiver')->default(0);
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('conversation_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


class CreateConversationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_one');
            $table->integer('user_two');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```